# SMOTE and Sequential Feature Selection Order

Tags: machine-learning, python, unbalanced-classes, hyperparameter, smote

Good morning,

I am doing the following procedure:

**Split a Train a Test Dataset**

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
X_pre, 
y, 
random_state=0, 
stratify=y,
train_size=training_fraction
)
```

**Apply SMOTE or Some other Balancing Algorithm**

```py
X_imputed_train_df, y_train = balancing_algorithm.fit_resample(
X_imputed_train_df, 
y_train
)
```

**Apply Sequential Feature Selection**

```py
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=8, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

                            sfsLR = SFS(estimator=lr1, 
                                       k_features='best',
                                       forward=boolean_sfs, 
                                       floating=False, 
                                       scoring='f1',
                                       cv=sss)
sfs = sfs.fit(X_ADASYN3, labels6)
selected_feature_indices = list(sfs.k_feature_idx_)
sfsFinal = X_ADASYN3.iloc[:, selected_feature_indices]
sfsFinal.columns = X_ADASYN3.columns[selected_feature_indices]
```

**Do HyperParameter Tuning**

```py
pipe_lr = Pipeline([('lr2',lr2)])
pipe.fit(sfsFinal, labels6)
pipe_lr = Pipeline([('lr2',lr2)])
lr_grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_lr,
                            param_grid=lr_param_grid,
                            scoring='f1',
                            cv=sss)
```

My question is: I am applying SMOTE to my full dataset, but not doing it for just the training sets of the cross validation. Is this a must? If so, how could I incorporate it in my code?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Any kind of “trick” you pull should exclude the test data, though you will find a dim view of SMOTE here. Perhaps you could say why you want to use SMOTE at all.

Comment: [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352)

Comment: [Algorithms for automatic model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: SMOTE is a completely invalid method, and any wish to use it implies a lack of understanding of statistics and prediction.  More [here](https://fharrell.com/post/classification).  SMOTE will also make classification fail to work on new datasets that are not smitten.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I see SMOTE is viewed badly. I will go in detail through the referenced posts. The reason I have been using it, is that it gives overall better F1 scores when I am experimenting with my model (By changing the scalers, imputers, etc.). Isnt the end-point getting an F1 score from your test data? I have used Stratified Shuffle Split for Sequential Feature Selection and Hyperparameter tuning.

Comment: `Isnt the end-point getting an F1 score from your test data?` See what you think about that after you read the link from Harrell or Kolassa. :)